# Web browser Wait for a button to load

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a code that finds a specific button in the web browser page and clicks it two times. The problem is that when the button is first clicked it has a short loading before becoming clickable again so when it gets clicked the second time it doesn't work because it's still loading. I basically need a way to tell the program to wait until the button is loaded to than click it again.
Here is my code:

```
var links = webpage.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "something")
                {
                    link.InvokeMember("click");
                }               
            }
            links = webpage.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "something")
            {
                link.InvokeMember("click");
            }                
        }
```

I already tried with `Thread-Sleep()` but it freezes the browser and the button doesn't load. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var links = webpage.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "something")
    {
        link.InvokeMember("click");
    }               
}
links = webpage.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{

    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "something")
    {
    while (!link.Enabled) 
        { 
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        }
        link.InvokeMember("click");
    }                
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, still doesn't click the second time but anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: The HTML page matters can you provide the link?

Comment: Hi found a solution in what I needed by using async await functions. I'll close my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Elvopresla np, glad you found it.